# What is the rationale behind apache's two remoteip directives; RemoteIPTrustedProxy vs remoteipinternalproxy

Tags: apache, directive, x-forwarded-for

`RemoteIPTrustedProxy` does not accept internal addresses like 10.0.0.0/8.

`remoteipinternalproxy` accepts all addresses.

When should you use one or the other. The rationale is, as far as I can tell, not retrievable from *Apache httpd*'s documentation.